# angular2 login and subsequent routing

Tags: angular

I have an angular2 application and I am adding login to it. So Login page will be the first thing that appears and if login is successful then rest of the app is accessible.

However I am not sure how I handle the routing. So far addition to all other components, I have created Authentication component with component.ts, service and html.

My top level app.component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app/app.component.html',
    styleUrls:['./app/app.component.css'],
    directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Navbar, Stepper, Cart],
    providers:[CartService, ProgressService, LoginService]
})

export class AppComponent {}
```

routes:

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [

  { path: '', component: Home },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }, <- I was just trying this
  { path: 'about', component: About },
  { path: 'hall', component: HallComponent },
  { path: 'caterer', component: CatererComponent }

];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

top most app html:

```
<navbar></navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**So on successful login I would navigate to 'Home'**

Login service:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService extends BaseService {

  public errorMessage: string;

  constructor (http: Http) {super(http);}

   private _authenticationUrl = this._baseUrl + 'rest-auth/';  // URL to web api


  login(username: string, password: string) {

    let body = JSON.stringify({
      'username' : username, 
      'password': password
    });

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    this.http.post(this._authenticationUrl + 'login/', body, options)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError).subscribe( data => this.setToken(data.key),
                                                        error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }

  setToken(key: string) {
    console.log(key);
    localStorage.setItem('auth_token', key);
    /*do routing here*/
    // this.nav.setRoot(StartPage);

  }
}
```

Home.component.html:

```
<div class="mdl-grid">
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">

        <p>Home component</p>
        ...
<div>
<hall *ngIf = "makeHallsvisible" [city]="specific_city" [date]="date" (setProduct)="setProduct($event)"></hall>
<caterer *ngIf = "makeCaterersvisible" [city]="specific_city" (setProduct)="setProduct($event)"></caterer>
```

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards

Comment: Angular routing has added guards for just this purpose. check out @GünterZöchbauer 's link

Comment: Sure! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to use is a Guard, here's a short tutorial on how to use it: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/18/guards-in-angular-2.html and here's a quick example:

Create a guard (authentication.guard.ts) with a code like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(): boolean {
        if (localStorage.getItem('auth_token')) {           
            return true;
        }

        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then in your route configuration just specify that your route depend on the AuthenticationGuard, define it like this:

```
{ path: 'caterer', component: CatererComponent, canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard] }
```

And you are ready to go!

Answer (score 2):

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
      { path: '', component: LoginComponent }, <- always redirect to login
      { path: 'home', component: Home, 
          children: [
              { path: 'about', component: About },
              { path: 'hall', component: HallComponent },
              { path: 'caterer', component: CatererComponent }
          ]  
      },
      { path: '**', component: LoginComponent }, <- redirect when undefined route
    ];

    export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
      provideRouter(routes)
    ];
```

add

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

in app.componet.html

and in home.component.html

```
<navbar></navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The idea is that app will be at login first and after 'login success' it will redirect to home containing navbar and other

Comment: So basically I modify my routes right with your suggestion? and also <router-outlet> in home? My home.component.html is pretty big. I am updating my question with it's contents.

Comment: if you place <navbar></navbar> in your app.component then you will see navbar in login page, too. Isn't that weired ?